# Installing apr-util-mysql on Oracle Enterprise Linux 7.1

Tags: apache-2.4, oel

I have a server running Oracle Enterprise Linux 7.1 which is basically the same as RedHat Enterprise Linux. Apache is not starting because it says `Can't load driver file apr_dbd_mysql.so` On my CentOS 7.1 server I was able to fix this by installing `apr-util-mysql`. I cannot find the same package for OEL7. This [package listing](http://mirror1.ku.ac.th/oraclelinux/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/latest/x86_64/) shows `apr-util` but no `apr-util-mysql`. Where can I find the package for OEL7 that provides `apr_dbd_mysql.so`?

The `apr-util-mysql` package provides:

```
$ ls /usr/lib64/apr-util-1/
apr_dbd_mysql-1.so  apr_dbd_mysql.so
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build the `apr-util-mysql` RPM from the source RPM.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# The RPM will be rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/apr-util-mysql-1.5.2-6.0.1.el7.x86_64.rpm

wget https://oss.oracle.com/ol7/SRPMS-updates/apr-util-1.5.2-6.0.1.el7.src.rpm
sudo yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"
sudo yum -y install rpm-build apr-devel libdb-devel expat-devel libuuid-devel postgresql-devel \
unixODBC-devel openldap-devel openssl-devel nss-devel sqlite-devel mysql-devel
rpmbuild --rebuild --define 'dist .el7' apr-util-1.5.2-6.0.1.el7.src.rpm
```